# Admob size issues

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add an ad to my app but I keep get this error

```
10-19 16:27:36.188  12856-12856/cf.cphn.notificationreminder W/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad. Needs 300x250 dp, but only has 296x533 dp.
```

My ad fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my main_activity.xml:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="cf.cphn.notificationreminder.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:name="cf.cphn.notificationreminder.AdFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Any other solutions I found didnt help, any idea on the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I think some layout padding or margin is preventing the adView from filling up the whole screen.

try removing this line:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
```

replace it with:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```